# Achieve dynamic height for UITableView (Slave) which is added as subview inside a custom cell of an another UITableView (Master) with dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a master UITableView with custom cells. The height of cells in this master table view is dynamically computed with auto-layout constraints. Now I want to add slave UITableView inside the master table view's cell. Please provide explanations on how to achieve this. (Sample projects may also be very much helpful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"

 @interface TableViewController ()
  {
    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSString *cellID;
  }
@end


@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

   [super viewDidLoad];
   array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi",@"13.861970 dsdlkdksjdksksdjkljkdlsjkldsjk dsdlkdksjdksksdjkljkdlsjkldsjkdsdlkdksjdksksdjkljkdlsjkldsjkdsdlkdksjdksksdjkljkdlsjkldsjk", @"Latitude",@"100.504250", @"Longitude",@"50 kph", @"Speed",@"1000 meters", @"Altitude",@"12/04/2010", @"Date",@"05:45 PM", @"Time",@"North west", @"Course", nil];
  cellID = @"cellID";

  [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
  [self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:50];
  [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellID];

}


  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1;
  }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:      (NSInteger)section {
   #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
   return [array count];
   }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

     if (indexPath.row == 1)
     {
        [cell addTableWithText:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     }
     else
     {
        [cell setCellText:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     }
return cell;
 }
```

CustomCellTableViewCell is implemented as following.

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

     @interface CustomCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
 {
    UILabel *cellLabel;
    UITableView *table;
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
 }
 -(void) setCellText:(NSString *) text;
 -(void) addTableWithText:(NSString *) text;
  @end



 #import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"
 #import "Masonry.h"

 @implementation CustomCellTableViewCell


-(void) setCellText:(NSString *) text
 {
    if (cellLabel == nil)
    {
      cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
      [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
      [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
      [self addSubview:cellLabel];

      [cellLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self).with.insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10,10));
       }];
     }
    [cellLabel setText:text];
  }



-(void) addTableWithText:(NSString *) text
 {
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9", nil];

if (table == nil)
{
    table = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    [table setDelegate:self];
    [table setDataSource:self];
    [table setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [table setEstimatedRowHeight:40];
    [table setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
    [self addSubview:table];

    [table registerClass:[CustomCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    [table mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(self);
        make.left.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
        make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
    }];
}
if (cellLabel == nil)
{
    cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:cellLabel];

    [cellLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.top.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
        make.left.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
        make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
        make.bottom.equalTo(table.mas_top).with.offset(-10);
    }];
}
else
{
    [cellLabel mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
        make.left.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
        make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
        make.bottom.equalTo(table.mas_top).with.offset(-10);
    }];
}

[cellLabel setText:text];
[table layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat height = table.contentSize.height;

[table mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.top.greaterThanOrEqualTo(self);
    make.left.equalTo(self).with.offset(10);
    make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self).with.offset(-10);
    make.height.equalTo([NSNumber numberWithFloat:height]);
}];
}


 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
     return 1;
   }


 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return [tableData count];
  }


 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
     [cell setCellText:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     return cell;
 }
 @end
```